# sending a PDF with google apps script - invalid argument

Tags: google-apps-script

What am I doing wrong here? I keep getting `Exception: Invalid argument: fileName.` The line it cites is 274, which the last line in the code below (`GmailApp.sendEmail`). (It's not a problem with the email address, subject, or body strings, I tried typing those all in manually and I get the same error.)

```
  var date = new Date();
    var zone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, zone, 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm a');
  var docName = "title here - " + formattedDate;
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(docName);
  var docFiles = DriveApp.getFilesByName(docName);
  var docFile = docFiles.next();
  var noteBody = doc.getBody();

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var title = form.getTitle();
  var items = form.getItems(); //includes non-question items
  var responseSet = form.getResponses();
  var lastResponse = responseSet.length - 1;
  var itemResponse = responseSet[lastResponse].getItemResponses();

 //a bunch of code here puts stuff into the doc. I think that's not needed to share here, but I can if it is.

 // create PDF from doc
  doc.saveAndClose();
  var pdfBlob = docFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  var newPDF = docFolder.createFile(pdfBlob);
  newPDF.setName(title + " - " + formattedDate);
  docFile.setTrashed(true);

  var recipientEmail = itemResponse[1].getResponse();
  var subject = title;
  var body = "Check out the PDF form attached!";
  var pdfFileId = newPDF.getId(); 
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFileId);
  var pdfBlob = pdfFile.getBlob();

//Send email with attachment
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, body, {attachments: [pdfBlob]});
```

Comment: The question includes only a snippet of code. The error message references a variable `filename` but this is not defined in the snippet. Please include the whole script, and also include the full details of the error message (which will cite the line that is causing the error).

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the file name of the PDF. When I changed it to say newPDF.setname("test") it worked. Putting punctuation in the filename is apparently a no-no!